# Вывести записи по алфавиту, wordpress и order by

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Есть такой код для Wordpress, чтобы сортировать записи:

```
    <?php
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page'=>-1,
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
); // задаем условия выборки постов
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $this_char = mb_strtoupper(substr($post->post_title,0,1), 'UTF-8');
    if ($this_char != $last_char) {
      $last_char = $this_char;
      echo '<h2>'.$last_char.'</h2>'; // первая буква записи
    } ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

В итоге получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, будет сортироваться и выводиться по первому слову.
Как сделать, чтобы сортировка была по второму?
Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Картинки должны быть в коде вопроса

Comment: Вторую букву получить несложно, примерно так: `$pos = strpos(" ", $post->post_title);
$this_char = mb_strtoupper($post->post_title[$pos+1], 'UTF-8');` а как будет работать сортировка, если фирма машины из двух слов `Great Wall` или `Aston Martin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортировка у вас правильная. Если вам нужно получать первую букву второго слова, нужно просто получить из заголовка второе слово (например, с помощью функции `preg_split()`) и далее продолжить выполнение вашего алгоритма.

Как-то так:

```
<?php
$args=array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
); // задаем условия выборки постов
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $words = preg_split("/[\s,:]+/", trim($post->post_title)); // разобьём заголовок на слова, используюя в качестве разделителей пробел, двоеточие, запятую. Добавьте что-то ещё, что может оказаться в заголовке
        if (count($words) > 1) {
            $this_char = mb_strtoupper(substr($words[1],0,1), 'UTF-8'); // получим первую букву второго слова (используйте mb_substr вместо substr, если используете многобайтовую кодировку)
        } else {
            // обработайте ситуацию когда заголовок состоит из одного слова
        }
        if ($this_char != $last_char) {
            $last_char = $this_char;
            echo '<h2>'.$last_char.'</h2>'; // первая буква записи
        } ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Получается, если три слова в заголовке, надо дописать if (count($words) > 2 и (substr($words[2],0,1)?

Comment: Проверка `if (count($words) > 1)` нужна для того, чтобы убедиться, что в заголовке более одного слова (хоть два, хоть десять - неважно). Иначе попытка получить первую букву второго слова будет приводить к ошибке (т. к. второе слово отсутствует). Нам важно только это

Comment: Другими словами, ничего дописывать не нужно, этот код работает на любую длину строки. А вот если вам понадобится вместо второго слова определять первую букву третьего слова, то нужно будет сделать так, как вы написали