Как сделать сортировку по алфавиту с выводом первой буквы?
Нашел на форуме вот такой код сортировки по алфавиту с выводом первой буквы


<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_post' => 1
);

$query_city_list = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query_city_list->have_posts()) {
    while ($query_city_list->have_posts()) : $query_city_list->the_post();
        $this_char = mb_strtoupper(substr($post->post_title, 0, 1), 'UTF-8');
        if ($this_char != $last_char) {
            $last_char = $this_char;
            echo '<strong>' . $last_char . '</strong>';
        } ?>

<div class="option">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_field('city-region'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>



Но выдает ошибку "Notice: Undefined variable: last_char in".
Можно как-то исправить код, чтобы эта ошибка исчезла?

Видимо надо объявить переменную. Похоже вы не все скопировали

Да, я понял, что не хватает значение переменной  last_char. Вот оригинальная ссылка - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309415/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83-wordpress-%D0%B8-order-by

Ошибка "Notice: Undefined variable: last_char in" возникает потому, что переменная $last_char не была инициализирована перед её использованием. Чтобы исправить это, нужно инициализировать переменную $last_char перед началом цикла. Вот исправленный код:


<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_post' => 1
);

$query_city_list = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query_city_list->have_posts()) {
    $last_char = ''; // Инициализация переменной
    while ($query_city_list->have_posts()) : $query_city_list->the_post();
        $this_char = mb_strtoupper(substr($post->post_title, 0, 1), 'UTF-8');
        if ($this_char != $last_char) {
            $last_char = $this_char;
            echo '<strong>' . $last_char . '</strong>';
        } ?>

<div class="option">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_field('city-region'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>



